# Scrollable table with fixed header loses feature when Chrome window is full screen

Tags: html, css, django, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Django website where the CSS shown below modifies my tables to have a fixed header and a scrollable body.

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';

.table-fixed > tbody {
  display: block;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.table-fixed > thead {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.table-fixed > tbody > tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.table-fixed > thead {
  width: calc(100% - 1em)
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Head</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          3
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          5
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          6
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          7
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          8
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          9
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          10
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The tables work and do what they are meant to do. The issue occurs when I am on Chrome and make the window full screen. The scroll bar goes away.

On the other hand, if I do this in IE nothing changes. I can make the window full screen, and the tables still have scrolls.

Any ideas what is causing this issue in Chrome?

Comment: I just checked it in IE and it is the same as Chrome, when full screen, there is no scroll bar. Isn't it because overflow-y is set to auto? If the table is not bigger than 600px then no scroll bar is required i.e. auto.

Comment: @henry, I am using IE 11 and the scrollbar does not disappear. I also tried overflow-y: scroll and the same issue occurs in Chrome when it is in full screen. From my understanding, the max-height or height defines how big the table no matter what the window size is. [Here](http://imgur.com/s2FSttI) is a screen shot of the site shown in IE full screen.